# Install Hoverfly in windows without Docker/Kubernetes

Tags: hoverfly

Looking at [Hoverfly](https://hoverfly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/introduction/downloadinstallation.html) installation it describe how to install using Docker or Homebrew or Kubernetes

I don't use micro services and don't have/use Docker/Homebrew/Kubernetes

Can I still use Hoverfly or I have to install Docker/Kubernetes to execute it on windows/linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's just executable you can [download it](https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly/releases/tag/v1.0.1)

And [Get started](https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly/releases/tag/v1.0.1) by running `hoverctl start`

Or for test add as [maven dependency](https://www.baeldung.com/hoverfly)

> To use Hoverfly, we need to add a single Maven dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.specto</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hoverfly-java</artifactId>
>     <version>0.8.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```